# spring boot 2 and SCDF / spring stream + gradle someone had a successfull compilation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to compile my very first spring cloud stream application,

but..

all available samples are based on spring boot <2.0.0 when I try to upgrade the spring boot version  ( with also  his requirements ( ie , expliciting io.spring.dependency-management ) )
every simple app fail to execute tests with this exception :
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

and with the following sample testclass :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SampleAppTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

even an empty application built on 
https://start-scs.cfapps.io

with 
`Time Source` + `Rabbit binder starter` based on gradle and springboot 2.0.0
fail to compile due to failed tests exception with same error

I've also failed to find a github code that use spring cloud stream and spring boot 2, 
so my question is.. someone succeeded using them together ? how ?

Thank you,
Francesco

Comment: Francesco where are you getting your samples from? Current samples have all been upgraded to use Boot 2.0 https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Also, the `ClassNotFoundException`, which class? Perhaps stack trace?

Comment: Hi Oleg, that repository you suggest build correctly but it uses multi-module project in maven, which is quite different form a gradle build (  a gradle build will have to use spring-boot-gradle-plugin )  and dependencyManagement , if from the spring initializr you create a sample gradle project with two dependencies as I've described ( but every other combination I've tried didn't worked ) it won't build , error : https://pastebin.com/d6iV8aXE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've found the problem, this dependency is missing :

spring-cloud-stream-test-support

Anyway,
I want to say somewhere that this whole project need a summary of dependency graph  , deprecated versions, and some microservice micro-example ( that works ) that use gradle and maybe kotlin

after reading the reference, I went to test my first app and didn't worked, tried to compile https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/trigger and didn't compile (already opened an issue), in reference there is written to use spring could stream app starters for bootrap application but didn't found an example for spring-boot 2 (which i need for kafka 1.0 binder) ,

then this repo is clearly outdated ( without providing compability graph ):
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters
says to go here : https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters

but those projects, say to build against 1.3, point to this repo: http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/ 
and I'm having serious issues trying to figure out what work with springboot2 which has been released a long ago, and also seems the only one that support kafka 1.0, guys It's a mess..

Thank you,
Francesco

------------------- ADDITIONAL NOTES:
this is an incomplete solution that I have found , because :
adding

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

works for the maven project generated from https://start-scs.cfapps.io with the details provided in my initial question,
**BUT, DOESN'T WORK** for the gradle one! 
so now I'm still investigating..

----- NOW COMPILE WITH GRADLE ... read below..

ok, finally I've figured out how to compile the generated application from https://start-scs.cfapps.io/ with specified dependencies in my initial question..
the final build.gradle file is :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-time')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support')

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        //mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:time-app-dependencies:1.3.1.RELEASE"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:time-app-dependencies:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"


        //mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:app-starters-core-dependencies:1.3.1.RELEASE"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:app-starters-core-dependencies:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}
```

Hope this can help someoneelse ;)

Comment: Please see my comment in GH related to this https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/trigger/issues/1#issuecomment-373682920

Comment: I've also opened a ticket in github : https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/issues/628 to promote changes

Comment: also this page https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/ doesn't show the version 2.0.0  of https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters , as available . There are tons of release train ( wich I'm still unable to check for  compatibility to spring boot versions ) the last snapshot release is Celsius which took me a while to figure out that still refer to 1.3.1 ( http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/app-starters-release-train-build/Celsius.SR1/app-starters-release-train-build-Celsius.SR1.pom ) so seems

Comment: that version 2.0.x doesn't have a release train, I'm a bit worried now about the transitive dependency version hell I'm going to fight with because spring like to autoconfigure dependencies too..

Comment: 2.0 app are currently in the process of getting migrated. Until that is over, we suggest to stick with released GA versions of the apps (1.3.x/Celsius line).

Comment: Hi, Francesco. Just as an FYI, we are trying our best to port the OOTB apps to 2.0 stack. Please bear with us until the port is complete. We have added an ATTENTION notice to all app READMEs indicating that. In the meantime, we highly recommend that you stick to the GA release; use the 1.3.1 release-train apps for now.

Comment: Also, Francesco, https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/issues/628 is in the wrong repo; we have a fork of this to host the OOTB stream/task apps. Please close it. We are aware of the port and we will update the fork when the refactoring work is complete.

Comment: ok than you all, I'll stay with 1.3.x untill the 2.0.0  is ready, I erroneously though it was.. :)